# Naming the endpoints of an half open interval

Tags: naming-conventions

```
int myRand(int min, int max) {
    ...
}
```

Are there better parameter names that makes it clear that `max` is exclusive, not inclusive. I.e. the function generates a random number in the range [min, max)? How about `lower` and `upper`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [min, supremum) and (infimum, max].